# Mysql utf32_unicode_ci and html charset utf-8 used, but character � appear

Tags: mysql, html, encoding

I have some text in French in a MySQL field, which appears correctly under PHPMyAdmin:

```
mentionné
```

The field is encoded as `utf32_unicode_ci`. (It is a `varchar(500), utf32_unicode_ci`).

but a call to a PHP script calling this parameter and outputing in html encoded in utf-8 returns:

```
mentionn�
```

Here is an extract of my php html header:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="fr-FR">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Might be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367133/utf-8-showing-correctly-in-database-however-not-in-html-despite-utf-8-charset?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, besides the database encoding, be sure you check the following:

- utf8 encoding of the FILES (js/php) (under ultra-edit, F12: save as UTF8-NOBOM)
- utf8 html content: `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
- utf8 of your db connection:  `SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'`
- utf8 of your query results: `SET character_set_results = 'utf8'`
- utf8 of your db client: `SET character_set_client = 'utf8'`
- utf8 of your mysql tables: `ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`
- utf8 of your db server: `SET character_set_database = 'utf8'` and `SET character_set_server = 'utf8'`
- in some cases, forcing utf8 in file is necessary when hardcoded values need encoding. You would need to add a comment on top of your file for instance, with `charset=utf-8`, so ultra edit or your favorite editor can detect it.

rgds.

ps: I don't know utf32 but somehow the logic should be the same

Comment: Yes, mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con); did the trick. Thank you.