# How to show greek language with js file

Tags: javascript

I have in "function.js" this function:

```
test{  
    contents = '<html><head><title>Υπολογισμός Φ.Π.Α</title></head><body bgcolor="beige">' + "Το αρχικό ποσό που έδωσες είναι : " + axia + " euro." + '<br><br>' + "Το ποσό του Φ.Π.Α " + foros + "%" + " είναι : " +
         teliko_apotelesma.toFixed(3) + " euro." + "<br> <br>" +
        "Η  τιμή του προϊόντος  χωρίς το Φ.Π.Α " + foros + "%" + " είναι  : " + posoxorisfpa.toFixed(2) + " euro." + '<a href="javascript:window.close()"><br><br><img src=image/Close1.png><br><br></img></a>'
      + '<hr size=5 width=100% color=red >' + '</body></html>'
    options = "toolbar=1,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=600,height=300";
    newwindow = window.open("", "mywindow", options);
    newwindow.document.write(contents);
}
```

I call this function for file1.html  the windows is open but is show this:

```
�� ������ ���� ��� ������ ����� : 110 euro.
```

Shown correctly is this in Greek language:

```
Το αρχικό ποσό που έδωσες είναι : 118 euro
```

If I place the function `test` in the `<head>` of "file1.html", the output is correct.

Why do I have this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql utf32\_unicode\_ci and html charset utf-8 used, but character � appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432758/mysql-utf32-unicode-ci-and-html-charset-utf-8-used-but-character-appear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you haven't saved the js file in UTF-8 format, hence the problem.

Use any editor and save it with UTF-8 (without BOM if that's an option).