# UTF-8 not representing data as it should

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to insert Croatian characters in MySQL database.

I have done all most everything but I still have a problem when I want to insert some Croatian characters.

What have I done so far:

1. I have downloaded and installed MySQL Server 5.6 hoping that I will see Croatian collation but I couldn't find it...
2. I have set entire database and each of the columns on UTF8-default collation
3. I have put this into my php script: `header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");`
4. I have tried all of the combinations such as (setting everything on cp1250, latin2-croatian-ci) and still no luck

Some of the inputs that are inserted in the database are: `æèæžš` and it should be `ćčćžš`..this was just for testing...

Does anyone has any idea of what I can do next? I really hope that there is some sort of solution for this particular type of problem.

And I am sure that a lot of people were hitting the wall just like me when we are speaking about Croatian characters in MySQL database.

EDIT:
Code for inserting ( this is just for testing so it's simplify)

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3306","root","admin","test");

 if (!$con)
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 $sql="INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES('ćčćžš')";
 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }else 
      {
        print '<script type="text/javascript">alert("ok")</script>';
      }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Do you run `SET NAMES utf8;` when connecting to mysql?

Comment: just use utf-8, nothing else. Now, what's the process that leads to the insertion? php? files? inputs? phpmyadmin?

Comment: sorry guys I forgot to put my php code...hold on a sec...

Comment: what is your text editor?

Comment: I am currently using notepad++

Comment: ok, see my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11432833/1291428

Comment: You are not storing the PHP file itself as UTF-8. That is your problem.

Comment: @Sebas I have tried exactly what you have said and still the problem persist.

Comment: go to php my admin and insert the same value manually to see

Comment: I am not using phpmyadmin instead I'm using MySQL workbench. I can normally insert characters in the database and I can see them as they should be but when I'm representing them then I have the same problem with encoding.

Comment: so your database is ok. This is only your php and html files that must be saved in utf8, and your database session (the one you open in your php file) that must be setup to use utf8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read UTF-8 character correctly, you can create your table like this:

```
create table patient(
/* your columns  */
)character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and to insert/retrieve your data by adding `set_charset('utf8')` in php:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Could not connect to database. Error: '.mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

$query="select * from YOURTABLE";
$result=$mysqli->query($query);

if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        //reading $row data
    }
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

and also, remember to set your html charset to UTF-8:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: $mysqli->set_charset('utf8'); this was the problem

Answer (score 3):

For Croatian do:

1. Your tables in the database must be `utf8_general_ci`.
2. Your files must be saved as `utf8 (without BOM)`.
3. After connecting to your database with PHP, add this `query('SET NAMES utf8');`.
4. In your documents `<head>` tag add `<meta charset="utf-8" />`.

Tested and it works ( for Croatian ).

Živio

Comment: Pozdrav. I have tried what you have said and it's not working for me. I am still not getting data in the right format...any more idea?

Comment: @denonth looking at your php code, do you have `mysql_select_db` after the connection?

Comment: no this is the code that is used for testing. there is no `mysql_select_db`

Comment: @denonth does this code successfully add the `ćčćžš` in the table ? Did you change your database coalition to `utf8_general_ci` ? In your n++, did you put [utf8 (without BOM)](http://superuser.com/questions/292086/how-can-i-enforce-so-notepad-uses-utf-8-every-time-i-create-a-new-file) ?

Comment: Done exactly as you wrote it..this is inserted instead `ÄÄ‡ÄÅ¾`

Comment: @denonth are you using HTML5 ? If not , put `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>` in your documents (.php) `<head>`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25732/discussion-between-vucko-and-denonth)