# MySQL isn't alowing me to have '<' or '>' as a value

Tags: html, mysql, special-characters, html-escape-characters

I am trying to read in text from a text box and store it into my database.  Security of my database is at first priority and special characters are second.  At the moment users can use basic special characters (!@#...ect) but not greater than or less than(<>) or (☺☻♥).

This is what the code looks like at the moment.

```
$temp = $tableName.".".$fieldName." = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($fieldValue))."'";
```

when I put in `<` or `>` i receive blanks in my database. 
and 
when I put in `☺` or `☻` i receive `?` as an input.

Any input on this would be nice.  Thank you.

Comment: Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.

Quoted from [http://php.net/strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should use be using mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I put in '<' or '>' i receive blanks in my database.

That's what the [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) method does

> and when I put in '☺' or '☻' i receive '?' as an input.

That's an [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432833/1291428) problem.

As for

> Security of my database is at first priority

I suggest you migrate your code to prepared statements (mysqli or pdo).

Comment: Well i am working on moving to mysqli but at the moment but fort this problem I can't.

Answer (score 3):

It is not related to database, it is related to strip_tags() function which strips HTML and PHP tags from a string

Comment: First part is right. The other characters are probably showing as `?` because the character set on the table doesn't support those characters

Comment: actually, it can be. m_r_e_s requires a live connection to the DB to operate, which means db settings CAN trash strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) instead of strip tags. Strip tags removes any HTML tags from the string. The two functions I mentioned convert the HTML tags into html entities (a textual representation of that character eg `&lt;`) which means they can be outputted on a page as text and not be parsed as HTML by the browser.

Comment: ok so now the code reads

= '".mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($fieldValue))."'";

when i enter '<' or '>' it works properly however when i enter '☺'(alt + 1) i receive &acirc;?&ordm;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help.  I found the issue.  The code that I am editing was changing the special character code from '&' to %HEX for database reasons.