# Error on accentuated characters with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

My problem is that what is written directly via PHP is correctly accentuated, but when the accentuated word comes from the MySQL, the letters come like this �.

I tried using the `html charset` as `ISO-8859-1` and it fixed the MySQL letters, but broke the others. One way to fix it all is to set my `.php` files to `ISO-8859-1`, but I can't do it, I need to use it in `utf-8 encode`.

What can I do?

---

**At the moment solution:** Include `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");` before the queries (only need to do once for each connection made). I'm still looking for a conclusive solution on the server, not on the client.

---

EDIT:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+

mysql> show variables like "character_set_database";
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| character_set_database | utf8  |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like "collation_database";
+--------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name      | Value           |
+--------------------+-----------------+
| collation_database | utf8_general_ci |
+--------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

These are the values of my database, but I still cannot make it right.

EDIT2:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
...
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root00--', 'eicomnor_db');
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Here's the PHP code.

Comment: Use UTF-8 for everything. What character set does your database/table/column use? If this is not UTF-8, perhaps the best approach would be to convert it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql utf32\_unicode\_ci and html charset utf-8 used, but character � appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432758/mysql-utf32-unicode-ci-and-html-charset-utf-8-used-but-character-appear)

Comment: I tried doing it, but I can't set the `character_set_database` and `character_set_server` to `utf8`. I already tried to use `set global character_set_server=utf8`, but it doesn't change.

Comment: @Sebas In the other question, on a possible restart, the error comes back too, doesn't it?

Comment: @LucasHarada no, i think it does not

Comment: _I can't set the character_set_database and character_set_server to utf8_. Why not? Do you get an error, or is it just not possible given some design constraints in your system? That sounds like your problem right there. (I didn't see your message, btw: please use @halfer to ping me on questions/answers that are not mine).

Comment: @halfer I succeded on setting the variables to utf-8, but it's not working yet.

Comment: Great. OK, so if you select a string containing an accented character **from your MySQL console**, does that work correctly?

Comment: @halfer Yes, it does.

Comment: Cool - that means your database is fine. OK, so can you edit into your question the smallest possible PHP script in which the rendering error is exhibited? Consider your UTF-8 character set as declared in (a) your HTTP header, and (b) your meta tag. For most browsers, just one of these is sufficient to switch it to UTF-8 mode.

Comment: Check your connection is UTF-8 too, as @Kzqai suggests.

Comment: With PHP do you mean a CLI script or browser output (HTML)?

Comment: @halfer I edited with the PHP code. The charset meta header on the top is set too.

Comment: Hmm, dunno. Try this, maybe, prior to the `SELECT` query? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: _The charset meta header on the top is set too_. But it's not in your script; please add that in, both to your version and to the version in your question.

Comment: @halfer The `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");` worked! I just wanna try to find how to configure it without needing to include it on every connection. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Excellent news. It could be a configuration setting in your my.ini, but if it works, I'd leave it in there - better to run it pointlessly than to risk having the problem occur again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");` before the queries (only need to do once for each connection made) resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First off, don't try to modify your php files in the direction of ISO-8859-1, that's going backwards, and may lead to compatibility issues with browsers on down the line.  Instead, you want to be following the path to utf-8 from the bottom up.

- The
  easiest thing to check is to make sure that you're serving your html as utf-8:
  `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in your apache config may help with that,
  and `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your html header will as well.
- The second thing to check is to make sure that the mysql connection & collation
  uses utf-8:
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html or http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Converting_your_MySQL_database_to_UTF8
- The
  final and most annoying step is to convert any data actually in the
  database to utf-8.  Back up your data with a standard mysql dump first!  There are a few tricks to simplify this process by creating a dump of the database as utf-8 and then putting it back into the system with the right collation, but be aware that this is a delicate process and be sure you have a solid backup to work with first!  http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Converting_your_MySQL_database_to_UTF8  is a good guide to that process.

Good luck!  charset issues with old databases are often more work than they initially appear.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Check the edit, please. I did what you said, but it's still not working.

Comment: That is potentially good, hopefully the charset mismatch is not in your database, which would be much easier to fix.  Just make sure that your client connection is set to utf in your mysql .cnf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf  And then run selects on the data in the database directly and see if the format matches.  If you can see, for example the copyright symbol or the accented letter when selecting from the database, then that'd mean your data is fine.  if not, the data may be garbled in your database despite settings for utf-8

Comment: The data is OK. The `SELECT` shows them alright. But in the web ones are still messed.

Comment: Ok, that suggests the candidates of: php's database connection.  Apache server headers.  Browser headers. Or html.

Comment: Try: 
`mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` (php connection)
`mysql_set_charset('utf8');` (php connection)
`ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');` (php code, shouldn't be this)
`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` (html headers)

In your code, in order, one at a time, and perhaps one of those factors will make the difference.

Comment: Well, like I commented to @halfer, adding `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");` makes everything work fine. Do you know how to fix it without having to write it on every connection?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38932/discussion-between-kzqai-and-lucas-harada)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)? As you know that the charset used on the DB is ISO-8859-1, you can convert to your charset (I'm assuming UTF-8):

```
// Assuming that $text is the text coming from the DB
$text = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you send the output to the browser, you need to ensure that the proper charset `<meta charset="utf-8" />` is set and that you don't override it in your browser settings (check that it's either "auto" or "uft-8").