# how to solve accentuation error on msql or php

Tags: php, html, mysql

**I've been trying to solve the punctuation problems for two weeks now. I've already tried a good part of the solutions I found on the internet, but the problem remains.**

My DB and all tables are `charset="UTF-8"` and I also tried `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_swedish_ci` and also `latin1_general_ci`
I'm also using `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my `HTML` codes

I tried adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');` which solved the problem of the data I'm geting from the DB, but the other part of the website that is static **(header and footer)** is showing �� instead of ã or í and I also tried `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` but diden't work.

these are some links that i tried to implement the solutions.[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282115/error-on-accentuated-characters-with-php-and-mysql)
[superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/978203/issues-sending-latin-accented-characters-%C3%A3-%C3%B5-%C3%A1-%C3%A9-%C3%AD-to-a-database-table-in-ph)
and others.

**Does the mysql versions as anything to do with it?**

```
<html lang="pt">
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Livros Publicados</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="profileDisplay">
    <a href="form.php" class="btn btn-success">Publicar</a>
    <div class="row">
      <?php getblogridposts("blogs");?>
      <!--bloggrids-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
function getblogridposts($table){
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");

  $sql="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC";
  if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($rowcount==0) {
      echo 'Nenhum livro encontrado';
    }
    foreach ($result as $bloggrid => $griditem) {
      echo '<div class="col-md-3 blog-grid-top">
        <div class="b-grid-top">
          <div class="blog_info_left_grid">
            <a>
              <img src="blogadmin/images/'.$griditem['profile_image'].'" 
            class="img-fluid" alt="fantastic cms" style="width:230px;height:250px">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr style="width:227px;">
          <div style="width:230px;">
            <h6>
              <a><b>'.$griditem['bio utf8'].'</b></a>
            </h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>';
    }
  }
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue in your database? And please try: $conn -> set_charset("utf8"); after you have connected to the db.

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored