# French Characters in SQL Text field to UTF - 8

Tags: c#, sql-server, encoding, utf-8

I have some french characters stored in a text column in Sql Server(not ntext but text). When I display this on html i get some funny question mark characters in the string.

Even if I convert the text to nvarchar(max) and display on html I still get the same error.

How do I convert the french characters in the text field to UTF-8 correctly? I am using C#, .NET 4.5.

Thank you,
GMAT

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx should be of help to you

Comment: It may or may not be a database issue.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11432833/1291428. Mostly this answer is for mysql, but some parts apply to any system.

Comment: It could be a mismatched HTML encoding. Try with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: `text` will not store French characters properly.  You need `ntext`.  Now, if you started with `text` and then "converted" to `nvarchar`, you have already lost the unicode characters.  You need to use a unicode field type `ntext` or `nvarchar` and import the data fresh.

Comment: I think you are right Sam Axe

Comment: The content displays fine on a browser <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> but I am trying to send the content to a web service using Content type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it thus:

```
Encoding wind1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] wind125Bytes = wind1252.GetBytes(input);
byte[] data = Encoding.Convert(wind1252, utf8, wind125Bytes);
```