# Umlauts and special characters are not displayed in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, encode

I have written a small social network on my pc in my localhost xampp. 
Here everything works fine.

Text in my mySQL Database looks like this: "was fÃ¼r pizza?" instead of "was für Pizza?".
This is fine, it is displayed like "was für Pizza?" in my localhost on my PC.

But now I uploaded it to my Webspace and there I got this "was fÃ¼r pizza?" displayed.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10924295/1291428

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AddDefaultCharset

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367133/utf-8-showing-correctly-in-database-however-not-in-html-despite-utf-8-charset?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some steps:

- Make sure your table/columns are set to a unicode collation.  An older, but still good one is utf8_unicode_ci.  It works for most cases, but if you're going to have emoji (which you might with a social network) you'll want to use utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
- Make sure that PHP's connection with the database is UTF8.  This is generally accomplished by running the query `SET names 'utf8'`
- Make sure your website is telling the browser that it's UTF8.  This is generally accomplished by sending the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` header, by including a meta tag that says the same thing, `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` or by including a meta-charset tag (newer) `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: i did these steps, but it didn't help :/

Comment: @progNewFag If using utf8_decode() fixed your problem than it's because your page isn't being interpreted in UTF-8 (or some step between your database and output isn't UTF-8; as utf8_decode transform UTF into ISO-8859-1.

Comment: so how can i fix this? Where lies the mistake that the page isn't interpreted in UTF-8?

Comment: @progNewFag without seeing the page there's not much I can help you with.  You should double check the content-type header and make sure you have the charset=utf-8 tag

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with character encoding, you need to use utf-8. I think the default is ascII. I only write pages in English but this [guy](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/) has all of the steps needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the file to UTF8 using notepad plus plus.
Try it.